# Kotlin equivalent of "export default" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, kotlin

I'm trying to use Kotlin for building my React Native app and am currently converting preexisting JavaScript code to it. However I don't know what Kotlin equivalent of `export default` would be. Is there even a need for such code?

The JS class I'm trying to convert:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, Kotlin/JS compiler works per-module, i.e. generates single JavaScript file for a set of Kotlin source files marked as a module (either module in IDEA, project in Gradle or module Maven). If you set `moduleKind` compiler option to either `commonjs` or `umd` value, Kotlin/JS will turn this file into CommonJS module, with root package exported and all dependant modules imported. There's no direct equivalent of JavaScript code you provided, so you perhaps need to change how your class gets imported.

Consider you declare something like this in Kotlin:

```
package my.pkg

class App : React.Component() {
    // some code here
}
```

in a module named `myModule`. You can import `App` class into JavaScript by the following code:

```
const App = require('myModule').my.pkg.App
```

For more information about how Kotlin/JS interacts with JavaScript, see documentation:

- on [module systems](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-modules.html) (including CommonJS);
- on [calling Kotlin from JavaScript](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html);
- on [calling JavaScript from Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html).